# How do I solve quadratic double inequalities?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I have two questions involving quadratic double inequalities.

Firstly, what are the steps to get the solution for the following?

$0\le(x+2)^2\le4$

My my thought was to separate the inequality into

$0\le(x+2)^2$ and $(x+2)^2\le4$

Which would then allow me to take the square root of each side of the and.

$0\le x+2$ and $0\ge x+2$ and $x+2 \le 2$ and $x+2 \ge -2$

Which could be simplified to $x+2 \le 2$ and $x+2 \ge -2$

And combined into

$-2 \le x+2 \le 2$

Is this the proper way to think about/solve this problem? Is there a better way to approach it?

Secondly, what strategy could I use to square both sides of 
$-2\le x+2\le2$ to get back $0\le(x+2)^2\le4$

Thanks!

Comment: In this specific example, the left inequality holds anyway, so you only have to care for the right one. In general, your approach to seperate the inequalities is perfectly valid, and usually we won't find anything much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $0 \leq (x+2)^2$, we know that any real number squared is always positive so this can be ignored.

As $4 \geq (x+2)^2$, then over here $x+2$ is between $-2$ and $2$, so $x$ is between $-4$ and $0$, respectively.

$-4 \leq x \leq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: One quibble, $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, but $0^2 = 0$ is not a positive number, so it would be better to say that the square of a real number is always nonnegative.

Answer (score 3):

For real $x,$

$$(x+2)^2\ge0$$

So, the problem reduces to $$(x+2)^2\le4\iff x(x+4)\le0$$

$\implies$

either

$x\ge0$ and $x+4\le0\iff 0\le x\le-4$ which is impossible

or $x\le0$ and $x+4\ge0\implies -4\le x\le0 $

Answer (score 3):

$$0 \le (x+2)^2 \le 4$$ implies $$-2 \le x+2 \le 2.$$  Therefore, $$-4 \le x \le 0.$$  I don't see why it needs to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: Could you go into more detail how the first statement implies the second? It would make it clearer for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Option:

1) Set $y=x+2$;

$0 \le y^2 \le 4.$

$f(y)=√y$ is an increasing function:

$0\le \sqrt{y^2} \le 2$;

With $ \sqrt{y^2}=|y| $ we get:

$0\le |y| \le 2$;

$-2 \le y\le 2$, or $-2 \le x+2 \le 2$.

2) Rewrite:

$-2 \le y \le 2$ as  $|y| \le 2$.

Note $|y| \ge 0$.

Hence:

$|y| \le 2 $ implies

$ |y||y|\le 2 |y| \le 2\cdot 2$, .

$ y^2 \le 4.$

Answer (score 0):

You can say $\sqrt{(x+2)^2} = |x+2|$

$|x+2|\le2$

It is also trivial that $0\le (x+2)^2$